# Create a specific number of vertors for a list

Tags: r

I need to create a list of  "N" vectors with a length "L" that begin in number "B" . If I specify that N=3, L=4 and B=5. I would need a list of the following three vectors.

```
5 ,6,7,8,
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
```

I can do it manually one by one but I have sometimes 20 or 30 vectors to create with always different lengths.
I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand with this.

Cheers
Carlos

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with `matrix` as an output...

```
N <- 3
L <- 4
B <- 5

x <- seq(from = B, to = B + N * L - 1)

y <- matrix(x, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)

y    
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    5    6    7    8
# [2,]    9   10   11   12
# [3,]   13   14   15   16
```

Taking the matrix to list via transposition and data.frame...

```
as.list(as.data.frame(t(y)))
# $V1
# [1] 5 6 7 8
# 
# $V2
# [1]  9 10 11 12
# 
# $V3
# [1] 13 14 15 16
```

I'm showing it in this way partly because I've never liked the coercion of numbers to colnames, certainly other ways to handle that. The transposition may be removed if you set `y <- matrix(x, nrow = L)` instead. And drop the `as.list` because technically the `data.frame` is a list.

```
as.data.frame(y)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  5  9 13
# 2  6 10 14
# 3  7 11 15
# 4  8 12 16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` to get a list output.

```
split(seq(B, B + L*N - 1), (1:(L*N)-1) %/% N)
```